# Cakepdf image not showing with dompdf

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I'm using a **dompdf** engine of **cakepdf** to report with **cakephp 2.5.6**, but I need to show images from my DB and it does not works.

Use the `'fullBase' => true;` and nothing+ `define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE', true);` and nothing.

Controller:

```
public function boletasV($id = null) {
//$this->Comite->recursive = 2;


$this->pdfConfig = array(
    'filename' => 'BoletasV.pdf',
    'download' => (bool)$this->request->query('download')
);
    $postulacion =  $this->Comite->Postulacion->find('all', array('recursive' => 1,
    'fields' => array(
        'Postulacion.comite_id',
        'Registro.nombre',
        'Registro.apellido',
        'Registro.foto',
        'Registro.foto_dir'
        )));
    $comites = $this->Comite->find('all', array('recursive' => -1,'fields' => array('Comite.id','Comite.comite')));
    $this->set(compact('postulacion', 'comites'));

}
```

Config from `bootstrap.php`:

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
    'options' => array(
        'print-media-type' => true,
        'outline' => true,
        'dpi' => 96
    ),
    'margin' => array(
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ),
    'pageSize' => 'A4',
    'orientation' => 'landscape',
    'download' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8_encode'
    ));



define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE', true);
```

and this is my view test:

```
<td><center><strong>Candidatos para el Organo: <br> <?php echo $comite['Comite']['comite']; ?></strong><br><br><br>
<?php foreach ($postulacion as $postulacions): ?>
    <?php if($comite['Comite']['id'] === $postulacions['Postulacion']['comite_id']): ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('ovalo.png', array('fullBase'=>true)). ' - ' . $this->Html->image('../files/registro/foto/' . $postulacions['Registro']['foto_dir'] . '/' .'thumb_' . $postulacions['Registro']['foto'], array('fullBase' => true)). ' ' . h($postulacions['Registro']['nombre']. ' ' .$postulacions['Registro']['apellido']);   ?><br>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "show images from my DB?" What does the HTML produced by your code look like?

Comment: i dont know why, but in the next day when i posted this....thi problem are fade...but thanks for comment :D

Sorry for my english...yeah, not it's good :S